# Can I sign up for an individual account but name the account as company's name?

Tags: ios, app-store

> "If you enroll as an Individual, your personal name will appear as the “seller name” in the App Store. If you enroll as a Company, your legal company name will be displayed as the “seller name” in the App Store and you will have the ability to add additional members to your development team."

Can we create an individual account for Apple Developer Program but name the seller name as ABC Corp ? Will that affect anything when we change it to a business/company enrollment later on ?

The reason is that getting a DUNS number is expensive in our country and we are a small bootstrap startup.

Comment: No, Apple will reject your request. I tried it 2 years ago. But you can name it like ABC, not `corp` or `company` after ABC

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about Apple policies

Comment: This isn't about programming; it's entirely about your business's relationship with Apple. That's [not something we can really help with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) because [we're not Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).